# Passing Dynamic Button Data to a Hidden Input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog

I'm trying to pass one data-id from a series of buttons to a hidden-input field. However, the adEventListener doesn't seem to be working properly because it just cycles to the end, leaving me with hidden_temp_id set to the last data-id from the series.

PHP/HTML:

```
<?php
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select)) 
{
 ?>
<button class="openModal" id="edit_form<?php echo $row['id'];?>"  data-target="#id02" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"  onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'">Edit</button>
<?php
}
 ?>
```

Javascript:

```
    var openModalButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("openModal");
    for (var i = 0; i < openModalButtons.length; i++) {
        openModalButtons[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction(i), false);
        //console.log(i);
        console.log(openModalButtons[i]);
        console.log(document.getElementById('hidden_temp_id').value);
        console.log($(openModalButtons[i]).data("id"));
        }   
    function myFunction(i){
    document.getElementById('hidden_temp_id').value=$(openModalButtons[i]).data("id");
};
```

Comment: You're going to want to learn AJAX. Just a comment.

Comment: **it just cycles to the end, leaving me with `hidden_temp_id` set to the last data-id from the series.** what do you expect it to do other than that as every time the same input field is supplied the value i.e `hidden_temp_id`

Comment: I assumed that the hidden_temp_id would only be set upon the click. Also, I'm not sure how I would implement AJAX to load the data from the dynamic id.

Answer (score 0):

may be if you use the "id" like this

```
<button class="openModal" id="edit_form<?php echo $row['id'];?>"  data-target="#id<?php echo $row['id'];?>" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"  onclick="document.getElementById('id<?php echo $row['id'];?>').style.display='block'">Edit</button>
```